# Why doesn't Python's `re.split()` split on zero-length matches?

Tags: python, regex

One particular quirk of the (otherwise quite powerful) `re` module in Python is that `re.split()` [will never split a string on a zero-length match](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split), for example if I want to split a string along word boundaries:

```
>>> re.split(r"\s+|\b", "Split along words, preserve punctuation!")
['Split', 'along', 'words,', 'preserve', 'punctuation!']
```

instead of

```
['', 'Split', 'along', 'words', ',', 'preserve', 'punctuation', '!']
```

Why does it have this limitation? Is it by design? Do other regex flavors behave like this?

Comment: re-module supports zero-length matches as of 3.7.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a design decision that was made, and could have gone either way. Tim Peters made [this post](http://bugs.python.org/issue852532#msg19231) to explain:

> For example, if you split "abc" by the pattern x*, what do you 
>   expect?  The pattern matches (with length 0) at 4 places, 
>   but I bet most people would be surprised to get
>
> ['', 'a', 'b', 'c', '']
>
> back instead of (as they do get)
>
> ['abc']

Some others disagree with him though. Guido van Rossum [doesn't want it changed](http://bugs.python.org/issue3262#msg70749) due to backwards compatibility issues. He did [say](http://bugs.python.org/issue3262#msg73592):

> I'm okay with adding a flag to enable this behavior though.

**Edit**:

There is a [workaround](http://bugs.python.org/issue852532#msg19234) posted by Jan Burgy:

```
>>> s = "Split along words, preserve punctuation!"
>>> re.sub(r"\s+|\b", '\f', s).split('\f')
['', 'Split', 'along', 'words', ',', 'preserve', 'punctuation', '!']
```

Where `'\f'` can be replaced by any unused character.

Comment: Thanks for the links and for the workaround. I really think they should take up the BDFL's suggestion and add a flag for this.

Comment: This is a truly lame design decision. REs are a thing where design decisions SHOULD NOT be driven by what people "expect" because many things about REs are not in line with peoples' "expectations", whatever that means anyway. `x*` should match `'abc'` because that's what the RE says: "match an x, zero or more times". That's what you get when you use `*`.

Comment: Just ran into this issue as well when attempting to split a pascal case variable name (`re.split('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', name)`). Too bad.

Answer (score 2):

To workaround this problem, you can use the `VERSION1` mode of the [`regex` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) which makes `split()` *produce zero-length matches as well*:

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> re.split(r"\s+|\b", "Split along words, preserve punctuation!", flags=re.V1)
['', 'Split', 'along', 'words', ',', 'preserve', 'punctuation', '!']
```

Answer (score 1):

Python supports this as of 3.7, but only for fixed-width patterns.

```
>>> s = "You! Are you Tom? I am Danny."
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[.!\?])', s)
['You!', ' Are you Tom?', ' I am Danny.', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, split() is two different functions into one. If you provide a parameter, it behaves very differently than when called without one.

At first, it would seems that

```
s.split() == s.split(' \t\n')
```

but this is not the case, as you have shown.
The doc says:

[...]
If sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string
is a separator and empty strings are removed from the result.
[...]

Even adding a 'remove_empty' parameter it would still behave weird, because the default of 'remove_empty' depends on the 'sep' parameter being there.

Comment: I think you've got the wrong `.split()` - I was referring to `re.split()`, not the string method.