# Python: Moving a symbol to the start of the string?

Tags: python, string, plugins, sublimetext2, reverse

I'm trying to create a Sublime Text plugin (using python) that reverses the order of words in a selected string. I've got the main functionality working but now my problem is that every symbol at the end of a word (periods, commas, question marks etc) stays where it is, and my goal is to get everything reversed properly so the symbols should move to the start of the word.

```
def run(self, edit):
    selections = self.view.sel()

    # Loop through multiple text selections
    for location in selections:

        # Grab selection
        sentence = self.view.substr(location)

        # Break the string into an array of words
        words = sentence.split()

        # The greasy fix
        for individual in words:
            if individual.endswith('.'):
                words[words.index(individual)] = "."+individual[:-1]

        # Join the array items together in reverse order
        sentence_rev = " ".join(reversed(words))

        # Replace the current string with the new reversed string
        self.view.replace(edit, location, sentence_rev) 

    # The quick brown fox, jumped over the lazy dog.
    # .dog lazy the over jumped ,fox brown quick The
```

I've been able to loop through each word and use the endswith() method for a quick fix but this will not find multiple symbols (without a long list of if statements) or account for multiple symbols and move them all.

I've been playing around with regex but still haven't got a solution that works, and I've been looking for a way to change the index of the symbol but still nothing...

If I can give any more details please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show an example for multiple symbols, when you want to move them all.

Comment: And please note, that it is "jumps", not "jumped" :)

Comment: I don't have an example of multiple symbols, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Then, I see you managed to move ',' and '.' to the beginning of words, and I don't get what's the problem.

Comment: The problem is this will not move '...' or '!!!', and I don't want to write a new if statement for every symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `import re` you can change your `split()` line to split on the word break `\b` instead:

```
words = re.sub(r'\b', '\f', sentence).split('\f')
```

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713060/why-doesnt-pythons-re-split-split-on-zero-length-matches) for why you can't just `split(r'\b')`.  The above will give you:

```
['', 'The', ' ', 'quick', ' ', 'brown', ' ', 'fox', ', ', 'jumps', ' ', 'over', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'lazy', ' ', 'dog', '.']
```

Which you can then easily reverse and get your symbols in the correct place.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful and a way of doing it that I would of never thought of (or known). Now when then text is translated it adds all of the extra white space from the empty arrays. Is there a way to take them out? (I'm new to regex and I'm still trying to work out exactly what everything means)

Comment: @Sintyche You can remove the extra whitespaces in the result with a list-comprehension. Something like `[elem for elem in re.sub(r'\b', '\f', sentence).split('\f') if elem.strip()]`.

Answer (score 0):

I expect regex is a better way to go, but in case it helps ...

You could have a function that you call in place of using endswith ...

```
def ends_with_punctuation(in_string):
    punctuation = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '!', '?']
    for p in punctuation:
        if in_string.endswith(p):
            return True
    return False
```