# how to split numbers and characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings like `'english100'` and `'math50'`.
How can I convert them to a dictionary such as:

`{'english': 100, 'math': 50}.`

I have tried:

`re.split(r'(?=\d)'`

However, that does not work.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexL: This is a very strage limitation of Python. [It doesn't split on zero-length matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713060/why-doesnt-pythons-re-split-split-on-zero-length-matches), unlike any other regex flavor I know. And that's something you need to look hard for in the documentation.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Interesting, thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your strings are that simple, I'd probably do something like this:

```
d = dict()
d.update(re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)',"english100"))
```

Or another way (if you have multiple occurrences in the same string):

```
>>> dict(x.groups() for x in re.finditer(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)',"english100spanish24"))
{'spanish': '24', 'english': '100'}
```

Comment: Hi, in your `re.findall` function, what does the little `r` do in front of the string pattern?

Comment: @LWZ -- It makes it a "raw" string.  In other words, it prevents python from interpreting usual escape seqences (such as `'\n'` which python usually translates to newline).