# Python regex split into characters except if followed by parentheses

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a string like `"F(230,24)F[f(22)_(23);(2)%[+(45)FF]]"`, where each character except for parentheses and what they enclose represents a kind of instruction. A character can be followed by an optional list of arguments specified in optional parentheses.

Such a string i would like to split the string into
`['F(230,24)', 'F', '[', 'f(22)', '_(23)', ';(2)', '%', '[', '+(45)', 'F', 'F', ']', ']']`, however at the moment i only get `['F(230,24)', 'F', '[', 'f(22)_(23);(2)', '%', '[', '+(45)', 'F', 'F', ']', ']']` (a substring was not split correctly).

Currently i am using `list(filter(None, re.split(r'([A-Za-z\[\]\+\-\^\&\\\/%_;~](?!\())', string)))`, which is just a mess of characters and a negative lookahead for `(`. `list(filter(None, <list>))` is used to remove empty strings from the result.

I am aware that this is likely caused by Python's `re.split` having been designed not to split on a zero length match, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713060/why-doesnt-pythons-re-split-split-on-zero-length-matches).
However i was wondering what would be a good solution? Is there a better way than `re.findall`?

Thank you.

EDIT: Unfortunately i am not allowed to use custom packages like [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)

Comment: What is your regex? It also might be helpful to include why you are doing this, as there may be an easier way.

Comment: sorry completely forgot to include it between the lines!

Comment: You could just do `re.findall(s, "([^()](\\([^)]+\\))?)")` (Replacing the `[^()]` for all the characters you want)

Comment: Are the arguments just coma separated numbers?

Comment: For now yes. But in fact they might be strings as well in the future, so i guess i am a lot more happy with the `findall` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to find out all single character optionally followed by a pair of parenthesis:

```
import re
s = "F(230,24)F[f(22)_(23);(2)%[+(45)FF]]"
re.findall("[^()](?:\([^()]*\))?", s)

['F(230,24)',
 'F',
 '[',
 'f(22)',
 '_(23)',
 ';(2)',
 '%',
 '[',
 '+(45)',
 'F',
 'F',
 ']',
 ']']
```

- `[^()]` match a single character except for parenthesis;
- `(?:\([^()]*\))?` denotes a non-capture group(`?:`) enclosed by a pair of parenthesis and use `?` to make the group optional;

Comment: This solves the pattern much more elegant than via split. Thank you! :)

Comment: Just for clarification: The non-capture group is used to assign the ? to make that group optional, but not have it as a capture group such that when there are no explicit capture groups the whole match is returned?

Comment: Exactly. It is necessary because `?` only makes the character right before it optional, and if we want to make a pattern optional we have to group it.

Answer (score 2):

> I am aware that this is likely caused by Python's re.split having been designed not to split on a zero length match

You can use the `VERSION1` flag of the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). Taking [that example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2713060/771848) from the thread you've linked - see how `split()` produces zero-width matches as well:

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> re.split(r"\s+|\b", "Split along words, preserve punctuation!", flags=re.V1)
['', 'Split', 'along', 'words', ',', 'preserve', 'punctuation', '!']
```

Comment: unfortunately i cant use custom packages.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. This time the pattern recognize strings with the structure **SYMBOL[(NUMBER[,NUMBER...])]**. The function `parse_it` returns *True* and the tokens if the string match with the regular expression and *False* and empty if don't match.

```
import re
def parse_it(string):
    '''
    Input: String to parse
    Output: True|False, Tokens|empty_string
    '''
    pattern = re.compile('[A-Za-z\[\]\+\-\^\&\\\/%_;~](?:\(\d+(?:,\d+)*\))?')
    tokens = pattern.findall(string)
    if ''.join(tokens) == string:
        res = (True, tokens)
    else:
        res = (False, '')
    return res

good_string = 'F(230,24)F[f(22)_(23);(2)%[+(45)FF]]'
bad_string = 'F(2a30,24)F[f(22)_(23);(2)%[+(45)FF]]' # There is an 'a' in a bad place.

print(parse_it(good_string))
print(parse_it(bad_string))
```

**Output:**

> (True, ['F(230,24)', 'F', '[', 'f(22)', '_(23)', ';(2)', '%', '[',
>   '+(45)', 'F', 'F', ']', ']'])
> (False, '')