# Splitting on regex without removing delimiters

Tags: python, regex, split

So, I would like to split this text into sentences.

```
s = "You! Are you Tom? I am Danny."
```

so I get:

```
["You!", "Are you Tom?", "I am Danny."]
```

That is I want to split the text by the regex `'[.!\?]'` without removing the delimiters. What is the most pythonic way to achieve this in python?

I am aware of these questions:

[JS string.split() without removing the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514144/js-string-split-without-removing-the-delimiters)

[Python split() without removing the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter)

But my problem has various delimiters (`.?!`) which complicates the problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with regex `.*?[.!\?]`; the lazy quantifier `*?` makes sure each pattern matches up to the specific delimiter you want to match on:

```
import re

s = """You! Are you Tom? I am Danny."""
re.findall('.*?[.!\?]', s)
# ['You!', ' Are you Tom?', ' I am Danny.']
```

Comment: A minor plus:  if the substrings contain new line (`\n`) that we want to keep, we can pass `flags=re.DOTALL` into the `findall()` function, to make `.` also match `\n`.

Answer (score 9):

Strictly speaking, you don't want to split on '!?.', but rather on the whitespace that follows those characters. The following will work:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[\.\!\?])\s*', s)
['You!', 'Are you Tom?', 'I am Danny.']
```

This splits on whitespace, but only if it is preceded by either a ., !, or ? character.

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<=[\.\!\?])\s+', s)` to avoid an empty string as the last match.

Answer (score 7):

If Python supported split by zero-length matches, you could achieve this by matching an empty string preceded by one of the delimiters:

```
(?<=[.!?])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZLDXr1/1

Unfortunately, [Python does not support split by zero-length matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2713060/4295017). Yet the solution may still be useful in other languages that support lookbehinds.

However, based on you input/output data samples, you rather need to split by spaces preceded by one of the delimiters. So the regex would be:

```
(?<=[.!?])\s+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZLDXr1/2

Python demo: https://ideone.com/z6nZi5

If the spaces are optional, the `re.findall` solution suggested by @Psidom is the best one, I believe.

Comment: I think I didn't state my problem clearly enough. What if there are now spaces after the `[.\?!]` ?

Comment: Python has support for zero-length matches as of 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer use split method rather than match, one solution split with group

```
splitted = filter(None, re.split( r'(.*?[\.!\?])', s))
```

Filter removes empty strings if any.

This will work even if there is no spaces between sentences, or if you need catch trailing sentence that ends with a different punctuation sign, such as an unicode ellipses (or does have any at all)

It even possible to keep you re as is (with escaping correction and adding parenthesis).

```
splitted = filter(None, re.split( r'([\.!\?])', s))
```

Then merge even and uneven elements and remove extra spaces

[Python split() without removing the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter)

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to use `nltk`.

```
import nltk   
nltk.sent_tokenize(s)
```

It will return a list of all your sentences without loosing delimiters.

Comment: This works only if you are working with English text. In particular, the question is much more general about any delimiters. Further, as awesome as `nltk` is, blindly relying on it without understanding the inner workings of any library is dangerous.