# split a column into multiple lists, and keep deliminator

Tags: pandas, list, split

I have a dataframe, which I need to split a column on character "Y" and keep this deliminator. For example,

```
    import pandas as pd

    d1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': [1,2,3],'action': ['YNY','NN','NYYN']})
```

The output dataframe should look like this,

```
    d2 = pd.DataFrame([{'action': 'Y, NY', 'user': 1},
           {'action': 'NN', 'user': 2},
          {'action': 'NY, Y, N', 'user': 3}])

    in[1]: d1
    out[1]: action  user
            YNY         1
            NN          2
            NYYN        3

    in[2]: d2
    out[2]:  action user
            Y,NY        1
            NN          2
            NY,Y, N     3
```

I have tried a few questions such as [Python split() without removing the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter) and [Python splitting on regex without removing delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244583/python-splitting-on-regex-without-removing-delimiters). But they are not exactly what I am looking for here.

Comment: Is it ok if the last row reads "N, Y, YN"? If not, would you be okay if the first row was YN, Y?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need

```
d1.action.str.split('([^Y]*Y)').map(lambda x : [z for z in x  if z!= ''])
Out[234]: 
0       [Y, NY]
1          [NN]
2    [NY, Y, N]
Name: action, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
d1['action'].str.split('Y').str.join('Y,').str.rstrip(',')
```

**Output**

```
0      Y,NY
1        NN
2    NY,Y,N
```