# Split text with special appearance of '.{{' in sentences

Tags: python, regex

I am working parsing some information from Wikipedia and text in the dumps include special annotations for links and images in the shape of `{{content}}` or `[[content]]`. I want to separate the text into sentences but the problem arises when the point is not followed by a space but by one of the previous symbols.

So, in general, it must split when `'. ', '.{{', '.[['` happen.

Example:

```
prueba = 'Anarchism does not offer a fixed body of doctrine from a single particular worldview.{{sfn|Marshall|1993|pp=14–17}} Many types and traditions of anarchism exist, not all of which are mutually exclusive.[[Sylvan|2007|p=262]] [[Anarchist schools of thought]] can differ fundamentally, supporting anything from extreme [[individualism]] to complete [[collectivism]].'

sentences = re.split('(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s', prueba)
```

I paste the text here again to ease the reading

> Anarchism does not offer a fixed body of doctrine from a single particular worldview.{{sfn|Marshall|1993|pp=14–17}} Many types and traditions of anarchism exist, not all of which are mutually exclusive.[[Sylvan|2007|p=262]] [[Anarchist schools of thought]] can differ fundamentally, supporting anything from extreme [[individualism]] to complete [[collectivism]].

The output of this code is a list with only one item containing the whole text:

```
['Anarchism does not offer a fixed body of doctrine from a single particular worldview.{{sfn|Marshall|1993|pp=14–17}} Many types and traditions of anarchism exist, not all of which are mutually exclusive.[[sfn|Sylvan|2007|p=262]] [[Anarchist schools of thought]] can differ fundamentally, supporting anything from extreme [[individualism]] to complete [[collectivism]].']
```

But I need to get a list with three items like this:

```
['Anarchism does not offer a fixed body of doctrine from a single particular worldview.', '{{sfn|Marshall|1993|pp=14–17}} Many types and traditions of anarchism exist, not all of which are mutually exclusive.', '[[Sylvan|2007|p=262]] [[Anarchist schools of thought]] can differ fundamentally, supporting anything from extreme [[individualism]] to complete [[collectivism]].']
```

How can I fix my regex code? I tried different solutions but I couldn't get the desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does this need to be a regex? Why not just use `prueba.split('.{{')`?

Comment: @Triggernometry it should also be able to work with '. ' and '.[['

Comment: You may want to edit in an example of a string that contains `'.[['`, and explain why splitting on a period isn't sufficient? From what I can see, it seems like you're making this too complicated, so I assume there must be some odd cases that aren't in this post?

Comment: @Triggernometry The text above contains a ``.{{`` and a ``.[[`` which are the ones that aren't being splitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems you are trying to preserve the delimiter you probably want `re.findall()`. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244698/11199887 which is reproduced below and then adapted to your situation. Using `re.findall()`, you don't have to worry about the difference between `.{{` and `.` and `.[[`

```
import re

s = """You! Are you Tom? I am Danny."""
re.findall('.*?[.!\?]', s)
# ['You!', ' Are you Tom?', ' I am Danny.']
```

In the above example you'd capture not only periods, but also question marks and exclamation points that end sentences. Probably not a lot of sentences ending with exclamation points or question marks on Wikipedia, but I haven't really spent time looking for examples

For your case it looks like this:

```
prueba = 'Anarchism does not offer a fixed body of doctrine from a single particular worldview.{{sfn|Marshall|1993|pp=14–17}} Many types and traditions of anarchism exist, not all of which are mutually exclusive.[[Sylvan|2007|p=262]] [[Anarchist schools of thought]] can differ fundamentally, supporting anything from extreme [[individualism]] to complete [[collectivism]].'

sentences = re.findall('.*?[.!\?]', prueba)
```

or if you really want to split only on periods.

`sentences = re.findall('.*?[.]', prueba)`

Output from `print(sentences)`is:

```
['Anarchism does not offer a fixed body of doctrine from a single particular worldview.',
 '{{sfn|Marshall|1993|pp=14–17}} Many types and traditions of anarchism exist, not all of which are mutually exclusive.',
 '[[Sylvan|2007|p=262]] [[Anarchist schools of thought]] can differ fundamentally, supporting anything from extreme [[individualism]] to complete [[collectivism]].']
```