# Split strings and capture groups in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split, tokenize

I have the following string:

```
'Cc1cc([N+](=O)[O-])ccc1OCC(C)(O)CN1CCN(Cc2ccccc2)CC1'
```

and want to capture [N+] and [O-], that is, splitting and recovering them.
I do not seem to be able to recover them by using re.split.

```
re.split(r'\[[^\]]*\]','Cc1cc([N+](=O)[O-])ccc1OCC(C)(O)CN1CCN(Cc2ccccc2)CC1')

output:
['Cc1cc(', '(=O)', ')ccc1OCC(C)(O)CN1CCN(Cc2ccccc2)CC1']
```

and I am looking for something like this:

```
['Cc1cc(', '[N+]','(=O)','[O-]', ')ccc1OCC(C)(O)CN1CCN(Cc2ccccc2)CC1']
```

I am aware of edits like:
[Splitting on regex without removing delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244583/splitting-on-regex-without-removing-delimiters) or
[In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

Comment: You can use: `re.findall(r'\[([^\]]*)\]','Cc1cc([N+](=O)[O-])ccc1OCC(C)(O)CN1CCN(Cc2ccccc2)CC1')`

Comment: Use a capturing group `\[([^\]]*)\]` and match instead of splitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply the function re.split wrapping your function with parenthesis you get the desired output:

```
s = 'Cc1cc([N+](=O)[O-])ccc1OCC(C)(O)CN1CCN(Cc2ccccc2)CC1'

re.split('(\[[^\]]*\])',s)

output : 
['Cc1cc(', '[N+]', '(=O)', '[O-]', ')ccc1OCC(C)(O)CN1CCN(Cc2ccccc2)CC1']
```

Comment: I get this: ['Cc1cc(', '[N+]', '(=O)', '[O-]', ')ccc1OCC(C)(O)CN1CCN(Cc2ccccc2)CC1']

Comment: You might add a line or two of explanation, and show the actual result.