# Splitting Column in Pandas using Regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, split

My first question... I have a Pandas data-frame with a column `'Description'`. The column has a reference and a name which I want to split into two columns. I have the `'Names'` in a separate df:

```
#  Description                                   #  Names
---------------------------------------          ---------------
0  A long walk by Miss D'Bus                     0  Teresa Green
1  A day in the country by Teresa Green          1  Tim Burr
2  Falling Trees by Tim Burr                     2  Miss D'Bus
3  Evergreens by Teresa Green
4  Late for Dinner by Miss D'Bus
```

I have successfully searched the descriptions to determine if it has a matching name by using a regex string with all the names:

```
regex = '$|'.join(map(re.escape, df['Names'])) + '$' 
df['Reference'] = df['Description'].str.split(regex, expand=True)
```

to get

```
#  Description                                   Reference
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
0  A long walk by Miss D'Bus                     A long walk by
1  A day in the country by Teresa Green          A day in the country by
2  Falling Trees by Tim Burr                     Falling Trees by
3  Evergreens by Teresa Green                    Evergreens by
4  Late for Dinner by Miss D'Bus                 Late for Dinner by
```

But I want the corresponding (= removed delimiter) Name as an additional column.

It tried adding *? to the regex like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244698/12794755)

I tried splitting the 'Description' column by using the 'Reference' column

```
df['Name'] = df['Description'].str.split(df['Reference'])
```

I tried slicing the 'Description' column by using the length of the 'Reference' string like

```
# like: df['Name'] = df['Description'].str[-10:]
df['Name'] = df['Description'].str[-(df['Reference'].str.len()):]
```

but i get a constant slice length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Series.str.extract` to get both types of information from the original column:

```
regex = r'^(.*?)\s*({})$'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, df['Names'])))
df[['Reference','Name']] = df['Description'].str.extract(regex, expand=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                            Description                Reference          name
0             A long walk by Miss D'Bus           A long walk by    Miss D'Bus
1  A day in the country by Teresa Green  A day in the country by  Teresa Green
2             Falling Trees by Tim Burr         Falling Trees by      Tim Burr
3            Evergreens by Teresa Green            Evergreens by  Teresa Green
4         Late for Dinner by Miss D'Bus       Late for Dinner by    Miss D'Bus
```

The regex will look like `^(.*?)\s*(Teresa\ Green|Tim\ Burr|Miss\ D\'Bus)$`:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 ("Reference"): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(Teresa\ Green|Tim\ Burr|Miss\ D\'Bus)` - Group 2 ("Name"): the alternation group with the known names
- `$` - end of string.