# Splitting string at specific letters in python except when followed by another letter

Tags: python, regex

So I have the string

```
sequence = 'MYNSIYGSPFPKINPKVRYKTALERAGFDTKPRNPFSSQRNASTGSLQASVKSPPITRQRNVSAAPSVPVTMKSAYTASSKSAYSSVKGESDIYPPPVLENSERRSVTPPKNSNFTSSRPSDISRSISRPSERASQEDPFRFERDLDRQAEQYAASRHTCKSPANKEFQAADNFPFNFEQEDAGNTEREQDLSPIERSFMMLTQNDTASVVNSMNQTDNRGVLDQKLGKEQQKEESSIEYESEGQQEDENDIESLNFEPDPKLQMNLENEPLQDDFPEAKQEEKNTEPKIPEINVTRESNTPSLTMNALDSKIYPDDNFSGLESSKEQKSPGVSSSSTKVEDLSLDGLNEKRLSITSSENVETPYTATNLQVEQLIAQLDDVSLSRNAKLDMNGNCLNAVDRKASRFKKSSAYLSGYPSMDIPVTQQTSIVQNSNTNLSRQTILVDKGDVDEDAPSESTTNGGTPIFYKFKQSNVEYSNNEGMGSQETFRTKLPTIEALQLQHKRNITDLREEIDNSKSNDSHVLPNGGTTRYSSDADYKETEPIEFKYPPGEGPCRACGLEVTGKRMFSKKENELSGQWHRECFKCIECGIKFNKHVPCYILGDEPYCQKHYHEENHSICKVCSNFIEGECLENDKVERFHVDCLNCFLCKTAITNDYYIFNGEIPLCGNHDMEALLKEGIDNATSSNDKNNTLSKRRTRLINFN'
```

I want to split this string after every `'K'`, and `'R'`, except when either letter is followed by a `'P'`. What might be the easiest way to do this?

To reiterate: Split string at `'K'`, and `'R'`, not at `'KP'`, `'RP'`.

Comment: Please show us what your expected output is.  And you don't need such a long sample input string in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try splitting with a negative lookahead:

```
re.split(r'[KR](?!P)', sequence)
```

This would be the correct answer if you want to split *and* consume/remove the `K` or `R` letter in the process.  If you instead want to split whenever `KR` precedes (and `P` does *not* proceed) while retaining all characters, then we can't just do a simple `re.split`, because it does not support lookbehinds.

One workaround might be to first do a replace all and insert marker symbols at every place where a split should happen, e.g. `$`, which does not appear anywhere in your current input.  Then, we can do a simple split on this marker character to get the result you want.

```
sequence = 'MYNSIYGSPFPK...'
seq_new = re.sub("([KR])([^P])", r'\1$\2', sequence)  # insert '$' markers
result = re.split(r'\$', seq_new)         # split at '$' and consume the '$'
print result

['MYNSIYGSPFPK', 'INPK', 'VR', 'YK', 'TALER', 'AGFDTKPR', 'NPFSSQR', ...
```

### Demo

Comment: But that would remove the `K` or `R`, instead of splitting after it.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, which is why I'm surprised so many people upvoted this.

Comment: @Tomalak on the other hand it says _split at_ in the last sentence....

Comment: @SebastianProske `re.split` does not directly support lookbehinds, but there are a few workarounds we can do.

Comment: @Tim Not sure why you ping me? If you want to have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713060/why-doesnt-pythons-re-split-split-on-zero-length-matches added to the duplicate list, you should rather ping Wiktor.

Comment: @SebastianProske. You guys are both European, I might have gotten you mixed up.

Comment: Works just fine for my purposes, thanks :)